# Angular - Http request returning null for large queries

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, rxjs

I have an ASP.NETCore application in which I am having an issue when using http requests.

In my data service I am sending a get request to a .NETCore data controller which queries a database and processes the results. In a component I then subscribe to retrieve the data.

When I have a request which returns < 500,000 results the code works fine and the results are as expected, however when the query returns more data than this I receive a null value as the result from subscribing to the request. I have checked the data being returned from the data controller and it has no issues so I am not sure why I am receiving a null value.

```
getRawData(startDateStr, startTime, endDateStr, endTime): Observable<QueryResult[]> {
    return this.http.get<QueryResult[]>(this.baseUrl +
      `api\/InfluxData\/GetRawData\?start=${startDateStr}+${startTime}\&end=${endDateStr}+${endTime}`));
  }
```

```
fetchData() {
    this.results = [];
    this.subscription = this.dataService.getRawData(this.startDate, this.startTime, this.endDate, this.endTime).subscribe(results => {
        this.results = results; 
        this.refreshData();
    });
  }
```

If anyone could give some insight into why the value is being returned as null when I have a larger amount of data that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you may have hit a browser memory limit. what's the size of the data? as a side note, returning 500k items to a browser does not make sense in almost any case. and why do you escape forward slashes?